# AutoFit not works on Loop while setting `RowHeight` works on the same Loop

Tags: excel, vba

On the below code, I need to `Autofit` range then set `RowHeight` for that range to be not less than 40. 
The line code of Autofit `r.EntireRow.AutoFit` has no effect at all even after I commented RowHeight code. 
On contrary, RowHeight code works. 
In advance, grateful for all useful comment and answer.

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook    'Source Workbook
 
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = wb.ActiveSheet.Range(Selection.Address)
 
    Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add  'Destination Workbook
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(srg.Rows.Count, srg.Columns.Count)
 
    drg.Value = srg.Value
    srg.Copy
    drg.PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
 
    Dim r As Range
      For Each r In drg.Rows
       r.EntireRow.AutoFit   'Has no effect
'        If r.RowHeight < 40 Then r.RowHeight = 40  'This line works
           Next r
```

Comment: You are adding a new workbook, assigning cell value, pasting column width. What would you expect the "Autofit" on a row to do? In a new workbook with no formatting it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: @BrakNicku ,But RowHeight is kind of formatting, and it works.

Comment: Yes, applying any formatting should work, including Autofit, but the point is: there is nothing to autofit there, so it can't "work" neither using VBA nor manually.

Comment: The code runs for me exactly as I'd want it to. Where a source cell contains multiple lines, the values are copied across, the columns are copied across and then each row is then expanded/contracted to display the values properly. You can prove this by putting a break in before the autofit part, resize your rows and then continue execution to see them change. Have you tried performing your code's purpose manually - i.e. copy/paste special values into a new workbook, highlight the rows pasted and then autofit? That might help you identify what you're missing.

Comment: @CLR ,I replaced `r.EntireRow.AutoFit` with `r.WrapText = True` and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `r.EntireRow.AutoFit` with `r.WrapText = True` and that solved the problem.